# Can a swig template file know whether it being compiled for python2 ("swig -python") or python3 ("swig -python -py3")?

Tags: python, python-3.x, swig

Because Python2 and Python3 disagree about what strings look like, I have to generate slightly different templates depending on whether I'm generating for Python2 or Python3. SWIG provides all sorts of macros for dealing with strings in an agnostic format, but not one particular macro that I need.

The generated `mymod_wrap.c` by SWIG contains lines of the form:

```
#if PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x03000000
```

I tried including these in my template file, but that doesn't work.  SWIG has its own C preprocessor, and `PY_VERSION_HEX` is treated as undefined by that preprocessor.

As a temporary workaround, I'm adding `-DPYTHON=2` or `-DPYTHON=3` to my SWIG flags when building the template.  But it seems that the `-py3` flag itself should be able to provide some way of making itself known.  I've found the documentation on what `-py3` actually does to be rather meager.

Will I have to stick with my workaround, or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation mentions that `SWIGPYTHON_PY3` exists if the `-py3` flag is set, but even then, it appears that this symbol can't be used in templates.

Finally, in one of the test suite file I found a piece of code that used:

```
#ifdef SWIGPYTHON_PY3 // set when using -py3
#define is_swig_py3 1
#else
#define is_swig_py3 0
#endif
```

It turns out that if I place this at the beginning of my template file, I can then use

```
#if is_swig_py3
```

inside a template.